# Google maps api v3: geocoding multiple addresses and creating map markers

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Im trying to do this tutorial on http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleGeocodedMarkersFromXml.html

I have included the downloadxml.js on my server but it still doesnt work. The map loads up but no map markers. Can anyone help as I cant see why it wont work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function geocodeAddress(xmldata)
{
    var address = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('address')[0].firstChild.data;
    var city = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('city')[0].firstChild.data;
    var address_google_map = address + ', ' + city + ', ON';
    var info_text = address + '<br />' + city + ' ON';

    geocoder.geocode
    ({'address': address_google_map},
    function (results, status)
    {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, info_text);
      } else { 
        alert("geocode of "+ address +" failed:"+status);
      }
    });
}
 function createMarker(latlng, html)
{
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker
        ({
            map: map, 
            position: latlng
        });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            info_window.setContent(html);
            info_window.open(map, marker);
        });
bounds.extend(latlng); // Here we tell what are next viewport bounds
}
function initialize ()
{
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.2340684, -75.6287287);
var myOptions =
{
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    center: myLatLng,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions:
    {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    StreetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener
(map, 'click',
function ()
{
    info_window.close();
});

downloadUrl('listings.xml',
function (listings_data)
{
    listings_data = xmlParse(listings_data);
    var markers = listings_data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('listing');
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    {
        geocodeAddress(markers[i]);
    }
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {map.fitBounds(bounds);});
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
<listing>
<address>4123 Rideau Valley Rd</address>
<city>MANOTICK</city>
</listing>
<listing>
<address>4456 Rideau Valley Rd</address>
<city>MANOTICK</city>
</listing>
<listing>
<address>111 Bridge St</address>
<city>MANOTICK</city>
</listing>
<listing>
<address>777 Bridge St</address>
<city>Ottawa</city>
</listing>
<listing>
<address>1333 Bridge Street</address>
<city>Manotick</city>
</listing>
</listings>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code????  To see if an error is occurring or if you have data for your latlngs?

Comment: yes. Everything is the same as the example and should work. The example map starts at the default lng lat location then quickly loads the map markers. My copied version doesn't load the markers for some reason.

Comment: Looks like the code that example started with doesn't work cross-browser (the original example doesn't work for me in Firefox), not sure if that is what you are seeing.  I will fix it.

Comment: The example in the link works fine for me. But Ive tried to get the example working on my own sever and it just displays the map without markers although the html, xml and js files are exactly the same

Comment: What browser are you using?  I fixed it to work for me in Firefox and Chrome (I "borrowed the nodeValue function from geoxml3).  The other difference may be the mime type that your server sends for the XML data.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the map on your server that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I see few problems.. You are missing `function` declaration for your `geocodeAddress(xmldata)` function.. so change line 14 as:

```
function geocodeAddress(xmldata)
{
... other code continues here ...
```

Then it should work, I also noticed that you are not extending your `var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` object when you are adding markers so remember to add your `createMarker` function to contain it, like this:

```
 function createMarker(latlng, html)
{
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker
            ({
                map: map, 
                position: latlng
            });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                info_window.setContent(html);
                info_window.open(map, marker);
            });
    bounds.extend(latlng); // Here we tell what are next viewport bounds
}
```

Tested, and everything works after that :) Cheers!

**Edit:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function geocodeAddress(xmldata)
{
    var address = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('address')[0].firstChild.data;
    var city = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('city')[0].firstChild.data;
    var address_google_map = address + ', ' + city + ', ON';
    var info_text = address + '<br />' + city + ' ON';

    geocoder.geocode
    ({'address': address_google_map},
    function (results, status)
    {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, info_text);
      } else { 
        alert("geocode of "+ address +" failed:"+status);
      }
    });
   }
 function createMarker(latlng, html)
{
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker
            ({
                map: map, 
                position: latlng
            });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                info_window.setContent(html);
                info_window.open(map, marker);
            });
    bounds.extend(latlng); // Here we tell what are next viewport bounds
}
function initialize ()
{
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.2340684, -75.6287287);
var myOptions =
{
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    center: myLatLng,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions:
    {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    StreetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
   google.maps.event.addListener
   (map, 'click',
  function ()
  {
    info_window.close();
  });

  downloadUrl('listings.xml',
  function (listings_data)
  {
    listings_data = xmlParse(listings_data);
    var markers = listings_data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('listing');
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
geocodeAddress(markers[i]);
}
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {map.fitBounds(bounds);});
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to create scripts folder where you place your downloadxml.js , since it is using path as: `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>` Also dont forget to add `listings.xml`

So the files you need are organized as:

```
index.html
scripts/downloadxml.js
listings.xml
```

Comment: Ive made the changes above and still it doesn't work. Could you post your working code please?

Comment: Added & to be noted: the code wont work if you open index.html straight in your browser from folder or desktop.. it needs to be offered by the web server. (or it will say XMLHttpRequest error in your console since it tries to access that .xml file.) If the markers wont show up right away, wait a bit when they downloads or try refresh few times ;)

Comment: all the files are on the server and I have been accessing it by localhost/mapmarkers.html

Comment: just tried it without being on server and got the same map with no markers. I also didn't get any XMLHttpRequest error

Comment: Seriously, your javascript console dont say anything? Try jsfiddle.net with your codes or copy pasting.

Answer (score 0):

inspired by Mauno solution, I solved this as follows, if anyone helps:

```
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.388397, 0.235348),
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress(data){
    var content = 
            '<div class="bocadillo">' +
                '<div class="titulo">'+
                    '<a href="tienda.php?id='+data.id+'">'+data.nombre+'</a>' +
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="content">'+
                    '<span>Ciudad: </span>'+data.ciudad+'<br />'+
                    '<span>Dirección: </span>'+data.direccion+'<br />'+
                    '<span>Teléfono: </span>'+data.telefono+'<br />'+
                    '<span>Email: </span>'+data.mail+'<br />'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'
            ;
    var direccion = data.direccion+", "+data.ciudad+", Spain";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': direccion}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, content);
            }
        });
}

function createMarker(latlng, html){
   var image = "img/general/map_icon.png";
   var marker= new google.maps.Marker(
       {
               map: map, 
               position: latlng,
               icon: image
       });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        info_window.setContent(html);
        info_window.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Then, call them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           initialize();
           for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
               codeAddress(markers[i]);
           }
});
```